# Laravel - How to sort an array of objects in ascending order by ID

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, sorting

I need to sort an array of objects in ascending order by ID called $messages, I tried many things but none seem to be working. Here is what I tried:

```
public function getMessagesPage(Request $request)
    {
        $user_id = $request->session()->get('id');

        $user_second = User::where('username', $request->username)->first();

        $messages_1 = Messages::where('user_1', $user_id, 'AND')->where('user_2', $user_second->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
        $messages_2 = Messages::where('user_2', $user_id, 'AND')->where('user_1', $user_second->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();

        $messages = $messages_1->merge($messages_2);

        $messages = collect($messages);
        $messages->sortBy('id');

        return view('messages')->with('messages', $messages)->with('user_id', $user_id)->with('user_second', $user_second);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your collection with `sortBy()` but remember that the function returns the *collection sorted*, doesn't mutate the *original collection*, so you have to change this line:

```
//$messages->sortBy('id');
$messages = $messages->sortBy('id');
```

As better alternative you can get *all the messages sorted* with only *one query*:

```
$messages = Messages::where([['user_1', $user_id], ['user_2', $user_second->id]])
               ->orWhere([['user_2', $user_id], ['user_1', $user_second->id]])
               ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
               ->get()
```

This is the same as writing this SQL:

```
select * from messages 
    where (user_1 = $user_id and user_2 = $user_second->id) 
    or (user_2 = $user_id and user_1 = $user_second->id) 
    order by id asc
```

Comment: Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$messages_1 = Messages::where('user_1', $user_id)->where('user_2', $user_second->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
$messages_2 = Messages::where('user_2', $user_id)->where('user_1', $user_second->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
```

Remove the AND from the first WHERE. Eloquent knows that if you chain `->where()` clauses, to use AND between them.

Alternatively, if you are using **Laravel 5.3 or greater** you can pass an array to in a where clause

```
$messages_1 = Messages::where([
     'user_1' => $user_id,
     'user_2' => $user_second->id])
->orderBy('id', 'asc')
->get();
```

Alternatively, if the following  `$messages = collect($messages);` is correctly returning a Key / Value pair array, you should simply be able to use the following

```
return view('messages')
    ->with([
       'messages'    => sort($messages),
       'user_id'     => $user_id,
       'user_second' => $user_second
    ]);
```